# VBA SUMIF on Array

Tags: sumifs

OK, so I am wanting to do a sumif on a column on an array because I don't want to print to the worksheet in order to obtain a range type for a Worksheet.function.Sumif, the idea is to stay completely out in VBA code and write to the worksheet as little as possible. I am trying to optimize for speed:  4814 rows by 40 columns X 60.

The first column total is total of 197,321,164 is correct, the next columns are low and instead of going to quarter 40 the Else kicks in and everything after 8 is 0. The first "To_Quarter" in the array is 9 so with the >= I would think it would go to 9. I tried putting my Next I before the End IF but then it just asks for the For.

image of locals box: https://ibb.co/cgFQhxY

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub SumifONarray()
Dim arrQuarters, arrNumber_of_Assets As Variant

Dim I As Long, J As Long

arrNumber_of_Assets = Range("Costs_Number_of_Assets")
arrQuarters = Range("Quarters_1to40")

Dim MaxRecov_If_result, arr_Row10_Resolution_Physical_Possession_Expenses_To_Quarter, arr_Row10_Resolution__Max_Recovery_Grid As Variant

arr_Row10_Resolution_Physical_Possession_Expenses_To_Quarter = Range("_Row10_Resolution_Physical_Possession_Expenses_To_Quarter")
arr_Row10_Resolution__Max_Recovery_Grid = Range("_Row10_Resolution__Max_Recovery_Grid")

ReDim arrIf_Max_Recovery_Amount_Sum(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrQuarters, 2))
        For J = LBound(arrQuarters, 2) To UBound(arrQuarters, 2)
        For I = LBound(arrNumber_of_Assets, 1) To UBound(arrNumber_of_Assets, 1)

   If arr_Row10_Resolution_Physical_Possession_Expenses_To_Quarter(I, 1) >= arrQuarters(1, J) Then
                MaxRecov_If_result = MaxRecov_If_result + arr_Row10_Resolution__Max_Recovery_Grid(I, J)
                    Else: MaxRecov_If_result = 0
                    End If
                Next I
                    arrIf_Max_Recovery_Amount_Sum(1, J) = MaxRecov_If_result
                    MaxRecov_If_result = 0
                Next J
End Sub
```

I've uploaded a sample below with code with 10 rows.
https://easyupload.io/wfixds